# Storing 10 million objects and modifyign them in a fastest way for Java application

Tags: java, h2, mapdb

I have a requirement to deal with 10 million objects. There can be 10,000 updates for objects per second. 
I am not sure it is good to store all of these objects in memory (JVM as this is a java application). But as I need performance (10,000 updates per second) we need to use in memory somehow.

So I feel hybrid approach is the best thing. Like MapDB, MVStore ... 
Can someone help me to find best option?

If I can query that store with SQL that is also an advantage for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Get lots and lots of memory and use a 64-bit environment.

Comment: honestly with performance requirements like that if you are starting from ground zero you should probably use a cloud solution

Comment: Query available mem, start using %50 of that for least recently used cache for updates. Reads are from cache, writes directly to db and also removes from cache. Maybe?

Comment: You can store 100+ million objects in a ConcurrentHashMap and perform 100+ million updates per second. Without more information I would use the simplest solution which will do what you want.

Comment: If you need persistence I suggest Chronicle Map, mostly because I helped write it.  I have tested it with 1 billion entries and performing 30 million updates per second.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I would start simple with one thread myself. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks for comments, are you suggesting https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map ?  Regarding your 'billion entries and performing 30 million updates per second' what was the amount of memory allocated for JVM here?

Comment: Your search for a technical solution might be a good example of premature optimization, but you haven't provided enough detail to know for sure. 10 million 50 byte object would fit into ~500MB of memory. If this is the case, then any technical solution you're dreaming up needs to be weight against "spend $5 for another stick of RAM". (If you _require_ SQL queries, then an in-memory database may be a good option, but if not then you can use a `HashMap` like Peter suggest.)

Comment: @lasithc the heap size was 2 GB.  As Chronicle Map is stored off heap in a memory mapped file the size of heap doesn't matter too much.  The machine has 128 GB. If you don't need persistence, a ConcurrentHashMap is likely to be all you need. If you need persistence, try Chronicle Map.

Comment: @DavidS Regarding the object size. For a one object I have around 20 string properties. Lets say one property can store 100 character long string. So if one byte representing one char then 100*20 bytes per object --> 2KB. so 2KB * 10 Million  = 20GB. Am I correct here?

Comment: I think that's in the ballpark, @lasithc. Using some [String memory usage formula](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml) I found online, I get 50GB. I would run a real-world sanity check to see if that's close.